# A song in Pierre Martin's "Madame le Commissaire"

Tags: identification-request, french-language, song-lyrics

In the book "Madame le Commissaire" by Pierre Martin, Isabelle has dinner with her friends.
A song by Edith Piaf plays in the background and Isabelle thinks about the meaning of the lyrics.
The meaning is somewhat that there are good times in life and everyone can change.

What song is this?

Comment: Are you able to illustrate this with a relevant quote from the book? It might help with some additional details.

Answer (score 5):

All the clues are in the text. The name of the song is the same as the first few words of the lyrics: “Non, la vie n'est pas triste”.

[image: paragraph of text transcribed below]

> Auf dem Tisch standen noch die Teller mit den Essensresten, Clodine zündete eine Kerze an, Pascal schenkte Wein nach, seine junge Frau Jeanne summte zu einem alten Chanson von Edith Piaf: *«Non, la vie n’est pas triste et le bonheur existe…»* Isabelle dachte, dass der heutige Abend ein Beweis dafür war, dass das Leben nicht immer *triste* sein musste. Hoffentlich hatte die große Chansonnière recht: *«Tu peux tout changer…»* Kann man wirklich alles ändern, irgendwie von vorne anfangen und ein neues Glück finden? Schön wär’s.
>
> <sup>Pierre Martin, *Madame le Commissaire und der verschwundene Engländer*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Non la vie n'est pas triste

Long answer:
I have found the song - it actually has the same name as the lyrics. There is only a small part of the lyrics provided in French, however, in the end it was sufficient to find the song.

Comment: Could you tell us exactly *what* part of the lyrics led you to the song? Maybe quote the relevant bit in your question? As is the Q asks for a song in a book (without quoting any of the relevant song-related text) and the A says it was a certain song (also without quoting anything) - can you see why someone coming to the question later will not be able to understand the Q or the A?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).